# How to incorporate Quine–McCluskey Algorithm with Composite Specification Pattern

Tags: c#, algorithm, design-patterns, boolean-logic, boolean-expression

I want to incorporate the [Quine–McCluskey Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine%E2%80%93McCluskey_algorithm) with [Composite Specification Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specification_pattern).

First, let's consider the basics, the Specification pattern in C#:

```
public interface ISpecification
{
    bool IsSatisfiedBy(object candidate);
    ISpecification And(ISpecification other);
    ISpecification Or(ISpecification other);
    ISpecification Not();
}

 public abstract class CompositeSpecification : ISpecification 
 {
    public abstract bool IsSatisfiedBy(object candidate);

    public ISpecification And(ISpecification other) 
    {
        return new AndSpecification(this, other);
    }

    public ISpecification Or(ISpecification other) 
    {
        return new OrSpecification(this, other);
    }

    public ISpecification Not() 
    {
       return new NotSpecification(this);
    }
}

public class AndSpecification : CompositeSpecification 
{
    private ISpecification One;
    private ISpecification Other;

    public AndSpecification(ISpecification x, ISpecification y) 
    {
        One = x;
        Other = y;
    }

    public override bool IsSatisfiedBy(object candidate) 
    {
        return One.IsSatisfiedBy(candidate) && Other.IsSatisfiedBy(candidate);
    }
}

public class OrSpecification : CompositeSpecification
{
    private ISpecification One;
    private ISpecification Other;

    public OrSpecification(ISpecification x, ISpecification y) 
    {
        One = x;
        Other = y;
    }

    public override bool IsSatisfiedBy(object candidate) 
    {
        return One.IsSatisfiedBy(candidate) || Other.IsSatisfiedBy(candidate);
    }
}

public class NotSpecification : CompositeSpecification 
{
    private ISpecification Wrapped;

    public NotSpecification(ISpecification x) 
    {
        Wrapped = x;
    }

    public override bool IsSatisfiedBy(object candidate) 
    {
        return !Wrapped.IsSatisfiedBy(candidate);
    }
}
```

Now suppose I have a MacroSpecification and some MicroSpecifications:

```
public class MacroSpecification : CompositeSpecification
{
    MicroSpecification1 Spec1 = new MicroSpecification1();
    MicroSpecification2 Spec2 = new MicroSpecification2();
    MicroSpecification3 Spec3 = new MicroSpecification3();
    MicroSpecification4 Spec4 = new MicroSpecification4();
    public override bool IsSatisfiedBy (object candidate)
    {
        if (candidate is int)
        {
            return Spec1.And(Spec2).And(Spec3).And(Spec4).IsSatisfiedBy(candidate);
        }
    }
}

public class MicroSpecification1 : CompositeSpecification
{
    public override bool IsSatisfiedBy (object candidate)
    {
        if (candidate is int)
        {
            return (candidate > 100);
        }
        return false;
    }
}

public class MicroSpecification2 : CompositeSpecification
{
    public override bool IsSatisfiedBy (object candidate)
    {
        if (candidate is int)
        {
            return (candidate > 300);
        }
        return false;
    }
}

public class MicroSpecification3 : CompositeSpecification
{
    public override bool IsSatisfiedBy (object candidate)
    {
        if (candidate is int)
        {
            return (candidate < 1000000);
        }
        return false;
    }
}

public class MicroSpecification4 : CompositeSpecification
{
    public override bool IsSatisfiedBy (object candidate)
    {
        if (candidate is int)
        {
            return (candidate < 500000);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

I really only need MicroSpecification4 and MicroSpecification2 for a simplified, equivalent MacroSpecification IsSatisfiedBy method.

So my question is, is there a way to use Quine-McCluskey to simplify the macrospecification IsSatisfiedBy statement from four specifications to two specifications (or something equivalent)?

It would be nice to have to give Composite Specification Pattern (and without loss of generality) Pattern Designs in general some kind of "intelligence".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use Quine-McCluskey to do that simplification, because the simplification you're looking for requires that it be known that `MicroSpecification2 => MicroSpecification1` and that `MicroSpecification4 => MicroSpecification3`. Q-M only applies to simplifying equations of independent boolean variables.

You could rewrite your specifications in terms of the last 20 bits of `candidate`, and then use Q-M to simplify the resulting chaos of equations in 22 boolean variables: the 20 low-order bits of `candidate`; a single boolean which is true if any of the remaining bits in `candidate` is set and a single boolean which is true iff `candidate` is `int`. The resulting simplification would be suitable for chip design but probably not for any other purpose. Sorry.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.  I figured this would turn into something that was less than practical to implement in the "OOP" sense.